# MongoDB: Count array elements of a single record

Tags: mongodb, count, nested

I'm stuck when trying do to one operation for my application.

Lets say there is a "games" collection in which users can register to play. Only the players id is pushed in the nested "registered" document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55008814d6422512da0b2a3d"),
    "max" : 50,
    "opened" : "yes",
    "registered": {
        ObjectId("55008814d6422512da9u0b2a3d"),
        ObjectId("1029475634d64433456d0eudh3"),
        ObjectId("493475756fe6422512da0b2a3d"),
        ...
    }
}
```

The output on webpage would be like this:

```
Game 0000000000010 | Registered: 0/50   |   [ Register ]
Game 0000000000011 | Registered: 10/50  |   [ Register ]
...
```

When a player register, the number increments. Logic.

So my question is:

How do I count the number of players in the "registered" nested documents for each game in order to display `Registered: 10/50` ?

Hope it was clear enough, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to use the aggregation framework from here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

`db.games.aggregate([{$project: {gameId: 1, registered: {$size: 'registered'}}}])`

Comment: it's also probably more sensible to do this on the client side - just use `doc.registered.length` in your script which renders the page

Comment: I used the doc.registered.length method. It's working fine. I wanted to make it too complicated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: awesome @jodu38 - if it worked please remember to select it as the best answer :)